# How to set default language setting for iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I have an iOS app which has two languages Hindi and English(.strings files for both languages).

I want the app to be by default in Hindi irrespective of System language always it should in Hindi.

I have tried setting `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` as Hindi but It did not work.

Can someone suggest the best way to achieve this?

Comment: are you using localizable strings ? for localization

Comment: yes, I am using the .strings files.

Answer (score 1):

You can change application language and region for build scheme

[image]

Comment: if I archive the build with this configuration will it work?

Comment: no, this is useful only for run app from xcode. In case if you will archive, it will not work

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Base Internationalization` and in this file duplicate the localization in Hindi.

[image: Info tab]
[image: left panel]

Answer (score 0):

You can use below string extension i've made , I'm assuming you have .strings files you can set your language type on accordingly like im using CurrentUser.language_type (this value comes from userdefaults) I've already set it accordingly

**en & hi** are language types

Link(for language types) - https://www.ibabbleon.com/iOS-Language-Codes-ISO-639.html

Usage ->  label.text = "YourString".localized

```
  extension String{

                var localized : String {
                    return  CurrentUser.language_type  == "hi" ? localizedString(lang: "hi")  : localizedString(lang: "en")

                }

                func localizedString(lang:String) ->String {

                    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: lang, ofType: "lproj")
                    printlnDebug(path)
                    let bundle = Bundle(path: path!)
                    printlnDebug(bundle)

                    return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: bundle!, value: "", comment: "")
                }
        }
```

Comment: I tried this approach some I get keys only as values. I did not write extension on String I wrote global function for this using NSLocalizedString